# Obtaining field's object for displaying validation error message in redux-form

Tags: validation, reactjs, redux-form

I would like to do sync validation, but I have no ideas how to obtain the field's object

*validate.js*

```
const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};

    if (!values.firstName) {
        errors.firstName = 'Firstname is required';
    } else if (values.firstName.length < 5 || values.firstName.length > 10) {
        errors.firstName = 'Firstname must be between 5 - 10';
    }
    return errors;
}

export default validate;
```

*SimpleReduxForm.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form'
import validate from './validate'

const fields = [ 'firstName', 'lastName', 'age' ]

@reduxForm({
    form: 'simpleReduxForm',
    fields,
    validate
})
export default class SimpleReduxForm extends Component {
    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, invalid, pristine, submitting } = this.props
        const { fields } = this.props
        console.log(fields)
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit) }>

                    <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
                    <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text" />
                    <Field name="age" component="input" type="number" />

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={ pristine || invalid || submitting }/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The output of `console.log(fields)` from the source code above as below

[image]

> It's just an array not object

I have seen [sample coding](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/components/SurveyForm/SurveyForm.js) from the documentation as below but I have no ideas how to get mine to work

```
const { fields: { firstName, lastName } } = this.props

...
{ firstName.touched && firstName.error && <div>{ firstName.error }</div> }
```

Please advise, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [good example](http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/examples/syncValidation/) of how to do this on the redux-forms website. The gist is that you should render a component for your `Field` which will then have access to that input's data. For example, here's one of mine using some `twitter-bootstrap` error styling.

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, invalid, error } }) => (
  <div class={`form-group ${touched && invalid ? 'has-error' : ''}`}>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} className="form-control" />
    <div class="text-danger">
      {touched ? error: ''}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Note that you just need to pull out `touched`, `invalid`, etc instead of `object.property.touched`, etc.

I use this from my `Field` declaration like so:

```
<Field name="name" type="text" component={renderField} label="Name" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregg, I forgot to mention that I can do the coding style you have suggested but I'm so curious why I just cannot do as in this [example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/components/SurveyForm/SurveyForm.js), thanks

Comment: That example is using `redux-form@3.0.12` and the latest version is `6.0.5`, that's why. If you want to use a version 3 major iterations ago, I suppose it would work.